# Angular 7 Dynamic Content Projection

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to be able to tell an angular component to render another angular component based on dynamic data. I think this needs content projection, but I can only make content projection work in simple cases.

**Example scenario**

I have the following table data in vanilla TypeScript:

```
const headings = [
  { id: 'cat', label: 'Cat' },
  { id: 'nameIt', label: 'Type the name' }
]

const data = [
  { cat: 'Tabby', nameIt: (name) => updateTabbysName(name) },
  { cat: 'Ginger', nameIt: (name) => updateGingersName(name) },
]
```

I also have four Angular components:

- `simple-span` which renders text in a span. In this case, it will render the cat field.
- `text-input` which renders a text input. In this case, it will render a basic HTML input which will call the nameIt callback when the user inputs text.
- `my-special-cat-table` which will provide the `headings` and `data` variables and is *allowed to know about `text-input` and `simple-span`*
- `generic-table` which is responsible for rendering table DOM elements. *It is not allowed to know that `text-input` or `simple-span` exist.*

The aim is to have `generic-table` completely blind to the cell render components

Is it possible to achieve this in Angular 7?

Comment: Short answer is no.

Comment: Right now, there is no solution that would be 100% generic.

Comment: I think you are asking for something [ngx-datatable](http://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#inline) and [Angular Material Data Table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) already doing.

Comment: For anyone interested in where I went with this... We ended up switching to React. The fundamental difference is that React is JavaScript through the entire component tree, whereas Angular has a template language layer between each component. This means that passing an unknown/dynamic component down the tree is React is trivial, whereas in Angular it isn't currently possible. Or at least not in a generic way.

Answer (score 1):

There is `*ngComponentOutlet` directive for declarative dynamic components:
https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet

Keep in mind you need to have them all in `entryComponents` so Injector would know about them and their factories. If you post more code, we can try to figure out the exact solution.

Basically, what it does is resolves a factory then creates it with injector and adds to the view:

```
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver
        .resolveComponentFactory(component);

    this.componentRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
```

You can write your own abstraction with similar idea and have it work with any component you want. Strange that people here say that it's impossible now.

Answer (score 0):

You can evaluate creating Reusable Components with NgTemplateOutlet. Just a suggestion.

[Take a look at this example](https://alligator.io/angular/reusable-components-ngtemplateoutlet/).

Answer (score 0):

What you want to acomplish is to use content projection in a loop. Here is an example for Angular Material:

```
…
<ng-container *ngFor=”let column of displayedColumns” matColumnDef=”{{column.id}}”>
   <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>{{column.name}}</th>
   <td mat-cell *matCellDef=”let row”>
      {{row[column.id]}}
   </td>
</ng-container>
…
```

As you can see by usage code, you can create multiple templates and combine them in whatever way you want:

```
<my-component …
[itemTemplate]=”itemTemplate”>
   <ng-template let-item #itemTemplate>
      column id: {{item.column.id}}
      value: {{item.value}}
   </ng-template>
</my-component>
```

[source](https://medium.com/@tomaszs2/dead-simple-content-projection-in-angular-f5969c675003)